# Why are non-digits LIKE [0-9]?

Tags: sql-server, collation

My server's default collation is Latin1_General_CI_AS, as determined by this query:

```
SELECT SERVERPROPERTY('Collation') AS Collation;
```

I was surprised to discover that with this collation I can match non-digit characters in strings using the predicate `LIKE '[0-9]'`.

Why in the default collation does this happen? I can't think of a case where this would be useful. I know I can work around the behavior using a binary collation, but it seems like a strange way to implement the default collation.

#### Filtering digits produces non-digit caracters

I can demonstrate the behavior by creating a column that contains all possible single-byte character values and filtering the values with the digit-matching predicate.

The following statement creates a temporary table with 256 rows, one for each code point in the current code page:

```
WITH P0(_) AS (SELECT 0 UNION ALL SELECT 0),
P1(_) AS (SELECT 0 FROM P0 AS L CROSS JOIN P0 AS R),
P2(_) AS (SELECT 0 FROM P1 AS L CROSS JOIN P1 AS R),
P3(_) AS (SELECT 0 FROM P2 AS L CROSS JOIN P2 AS R),
Tally(Number) AS (
  SELECT -1 + ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 0))
  FROM P3
)
SELECT Number AS CodePoint, CHAR(Number) AS Symbol
INTO #CodePage
FROM Tally
WHERE Number >= 0 AND Number <= 255;
```

Each row contains the integer value of the code point, and the character value of the code point. Not all of the character values are displayable - some of the code points are strictly control characters. Here is a selective sample of the output of `SELECT CodePoint, Symbol FROM #CodePage`:

```
0   
1   
2   
...
32   
33  !
34  "
35  #
...
48  0
49  1
50  2
...
65  A
66  B
67  C
...
253 ý
254 þ
255 ÿ
```

I would expect to be able to filter on the Symbol column to find digit characters using a LIKE predicate and specifying the range of characters '0' thru '9':

```
SELECT CodePoint, Symbol
FROM #CodePage
WHERE Symbol LIKE '[0-9]';
```

It produces a surprising output:

```
CodePoint   Symbol
48  0
49  1
50  2
51  3
52  4
53  5
54  6
55  7
56  8
57  9
178 ²
179 ³
185 ¹
188 ¼
189 ½
190 ¾
```

The set of code points 48 thru 57 are the ones I expect. What surprises me is that the symbols for superscripts and fractions are also included in the result set!

There might be a mathematical reason to think of exponents and fractions as numbers, but it seems wrong to call them digits.

#### Using binary collation as a workaround

I understand that to get the result I expect, I can force the corresponding binary collation Latin1_General_BIN:

```
SELECT CodePoint, Symbol
FROM #CodePage
WHERE Symbol LIKE '[0-9]' COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN;
```

The result set includes only the code points 48 thru 57:

```
CodePoint   Symbol
48  0
49  1
50  2
51  3
52  4
53  5
54  6
55  7
56  8
57  9
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

`[0-9]` is not some type of regular expression defined to just match digits.

Any range in a `LIKE` pattern matches characters between the start and end character according to collation sort order.

```
SELECT CodePoint,
       Symbol,
       RANK() OVER (ORDER BY Symbol COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS) AS Rnk
FROM   #CodePage
WHERE  Symbol LIKE '[0-9]' COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS
ORDER  BY Symbol COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS
```

Returns

```
CodePoint            Symbol Rnk
-------------------- ------ --------------------
48                   0      1
188                  ¼      2
189                  ½      3
190                  ¾      4
185                  ¹      5
49                   1      5
50                   2      7
178                  ²      7
179                  ³      9
51                   3      9
52                   4      11
53                   5      12
54                   6      13
55                   7      14
56                   8      15
57                   9      16
```

So you get these results because under your default collation these characters sort after `0` but before `9`.

It looks as though the collation is defined to actually sort them in mathematical order with the fractions in the correct order between `0` and `1`.

You could also use a set rather than a range. To avoid `2` matching `²` you would need a `CS` collation

```
SELECT CodePoint, Symbol
FROM #CodePage
WHERE Symbol LIKE '[0123456789]' COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS
```

Answer (score 7):

Latin1 is code page 1252, in which [178 is 'SUPERSCRIPT TWO'](http://www.microsoft.com/typography/unicode/1252.htm). This is an Unicode [superscript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_subscripts_and_superscripts#Superscripts_and_subscripts_block): is **the character "2" as superscript**. According to the [Unicode Technical Standard #10](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr10/) it should compare equal to 2, see [8.1 Collation Folding](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr10/#Collation_Folding):

> Map compatibility (tertiary) equivalents, **such as full-width and
>   superscript characters**, to representative character(s)

The bug would be if superscript 2 would compare different from 2! Before you say 'but my column is not Unicode', rest assured: according to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143726.aspx) (see Windows Collations) all string comparison and sorting are done according to the Unicode rules, even when the on-disk representation is CHAR.

As for the other characters in your example, like `VULGAR FRACTION ONE QUARTER` and the like they do not compare equal to any number, but, as Mark already showed, they do sort properly between 0 and 9.

And, of course, if you'd change the code page you would get different results. Eg. with `Greek_CS_AS` ([code page 1253](http://www.microsoft.com/typography/unicode/1253.htm)) you would get the characters with code 178, 179 and 189.