# How can I output text until it is ascii in SQL?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

How can I output text until it is ascii in SQL?

Here is what I am trying to do:

```
DECLARE @input VARCHAR(20)
SET @input = 'text'

DECLARE @index INT
SET @index = 1

DECLARE @output VARCHAR(32)
SET @output = ''

WHILE CHAR(ASCII(SUBSTRING(@input, @index, 1))) LIKE '[ -~]'
BEGIN
    SET @output = @output + CHAR(ASCII(SUBSTRING(@input, @index, 1)))
    SET @index = @index + 1
END

SELECT @output
```

But in the end I am getting an empty string. Why? What am I missing here?

I am expecting the value of the `@output` to be `'text'` in the end of the script.

**UPDATE**

If I update the script to the

```
DECLARE @input VARCHAR(20)
SET @input = 'text'

DECLARE @index INT
SET @index = 1

DECLARE @output VARCHAR(32)
SET @output = ''

WHILE CHAR(ASCII(SUBSTRING(@input, @index, 1))) LIKE '[a-z]'
BEGIN
    SET @output = @output + CHAR(ASCII(SUBSTRING(@input, @index, 1)))
    SET @index = @index + 1
END

SELECT @output
```

It will work as expected. But here I just shrinked the set from all printable ascii characters to only small letters. Why does the shrinked set `[a-z]` include the `text` characters and the extended set `[ -~]` does not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A space is not a valid range delimiter so `LIKE [ -~]` will not work. That becomes a test for those three characters only.

You could check the ASCII code directly, rather than using `LIKE`:

```
DECLARE @input VARCHAR(20)
SET @input = 'text'

DECLARE @index INT
SET @index = 1

DECLARE @output VARCHAR(32)
SET @output = ''

WHILE ASCII(SUBSTRING(@input, @index, 1)) BETWEEN 32 AND 126
BEGIN
    SET @output = @output + CHAR(ASCII(SUBSTRING(@input, @index, 1)))
    SET @index = @index + 1
END

SELECT @output
```

[demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=d6bcc8eef7157095144e8bf4b9c0daa0)

Side note: It's possible to get [unexpected results](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/34730/why-are-non-digits-like-0-9) with `LIKE` ranges because the comparison is collation-aware.

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo. I meant `[a-z]`.

Comment: @manymanymore I thought it might be, but it was repeated several times in the question, so I assumed not, and you were using some sort of weird collation where that might work. You missed one in the question edit, so I fixed that.